# Converting binary data to string in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a string containing byte data.
How can I perform an in-place conversion to ascii string?

Comment: What sort of an ascii string do you want to see? A bit string ("0101110110"), hex ("0AFC43"), or just something marshalled into ascii to decode somewhere else?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Another way to play with binary data is [String#unpack](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-unpack).

Comment: Thanks - unpack('H*') did the job.

Comment: suppose the binary data is a representation of arabic text.. (text which i'm receiving as some giberrish like `Ù‚Ø±Ø¢Ù†`.. how do I unpack it to look like it's original arabic (ie using some arabic encoding or something)?

Comment: Is there a JavaScript equivalent to this?

Answer (score 7):

You can do so via using base64 which is a fairly universal way.

```
require 'base64'

str = Base64.encode64(data)
```

Comment: data needs to be convertible to String for this to work. 

Try, for example:

irb(main):002:0> Base64.encode64(1234)
TypeError: can't convert Fixnum into String

Answer (score 2):

**if u have a binary string lets say something like:**

> s = "01001101011011110111000101110101011001010110010101110100"

**and u wanna convert it back to ascii text in Ruby u can do like:**

```
s = "01001101011011110111000101110101011001010110010101110100"

(0..s.length-8).step(8) do |i|
    print s[i,8].to_i(base=2).chr
end
```

***Hope this will help someone :)***