# Text to Binary and Back Conversion in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a string that was placed into an array and turned into binary using .pack('B*'). How do I convert that binary data back into a string? .unpack('H*') is not the solution here, it returns a string of gibberish.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/515478/converting-binary-data-to-string-in-ruby . I think this answers your question.

Comment: unpack('H*') is not the solution here, it returns a string of gibberish.

Comment: @bf86 I have added the answer please check.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this in my **Rails Console** and got the following. I hope this will help you.

```
a = "Hello".unpack("B*")

## Output
["0100100001100101011011000110110001101111"]

a.pack("B*")

## Output
"Hello"

a = "Hello".unpack("H*")

## Output
["48656c6c6f"]

a.pack("H*")

## Output
"Hello"
```