# Converting binary (or hex) into ASCII

Tags: ruby

I need to convert a large binary string (a sequence of bytes) into ASCII like this [table](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.htm). I can also start with a hex string.

I read this post: [Converting binary data to string in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515478). I found a solution that converts to characters in the extended ASCII table. I could write conditionals for every case in order to convert, but there has to be an easier way. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you specified contains javascript code, that performs a conversion, on the page, not obfuscated:

```
    function OnConvert()
    {
        hex = document.calcform.hex.value;
        hex = hex.match(/[0-9A-Fa-f]{2}/g);
        len = hex.length;
        if( len==0 ) return;
        txt='';
        for(i=0; i<len; i++)
        {
            h = hex[i];
            code = parseInt(h,16);
            t = String.fromCharCode(code);
            txt += t;
        }
        document.calcform.txt.value = txt;
    }
```

I did not understand your task clearly, since if you’ll enter e. g. `EEEFFA` there in the form, you’ll get `îïú` as an output, what, in my opinion, is extended ASCII. But there is a simple way to achieve the *same* functionality in ruby.

```
▶ "EEEFFA".scan(/[0-9a-f]{2}/i).map { |cp| cp.to_i(16) }.inject('', &:concat)
#⇒ "îïú"
```

**UPD** As I understood from the comments, you want to convert every 8 zeros and ones to the respective ASCII letter. Here you go (assuming you have a long string, containing zeroes and ones):

```
▶ '010000010100001001000011'.
▷   scan(/[01]{8}/).          # allow only zeros and ones, scan by 8
▷   map { |e| e.to_i 2 }.     # convert to integers, base 10
▷   inject '', &:concat       # concatenate into one string
#⇒ 'ABC'
```

Comment: I probably shouldn't have included that link... I mean I want to enter something like "01000001".some_functions_and_things and get the value "A". Do you think you could help me with that? I'm not very experienced and I don't understand everything going on in your code. My program will only allow bytes 00000000 up to 01111111

Comment: `"01000001".to_i(2).chr`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for spelling it out for me.

Comment: You are welcome. Please note, that to allow only ASCII7, one should use `/0[01]{7}/` regular expression instead of the one I specified (note leading `0`.)

Comment: I love how you use `inject` to simultaneously cast the integers to characters and build the string. Very elegant. You may already know this but you can drop the `&` from `inject`/`reduce` (it knows what do to with a symbol; you don't have to convert the method to a proc first), starting in 1.9.3, I believe. You can also use `:<<` instead of `:concat` to add magic. :-)

Comment: @mwp I prefer to always specify an ampersand when passing a block. I sometimes read my code written a year ago :)

Comment: OK, but it's expensive, so at least keep the option in mind if you're writing performance-sensitive code.

Comment: @mwp WUT? How on the Earth that might be expensive?

Comment: Converting a symbol to a proc with `&` and passing it to `inject` (to `.call`) is more expensive than passing a symbol to `inject` (to send). I'm sure the performance difference is tiny, but it's there.

Comment: @mwp http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject there in source code is clear that receiving a block results in _less_ amount of instructions inside `case`. Benchmarks show the near results, but passing a block might be by no means slower.

Comment: Again, converting a symbol to a proc with `&` isn't a free operation.

Answer (score 2):

A slight variation on @mudasobwa's excellent solution, using an (apparently undocumented) feature of `String#oct`:

```
'010000010100001001000011'
  .scan(/0[01]{7}/)
  .map { |b| b.prepend('0b').oct.chr }
  .join
```

And hex, for completeness:

```
'627e29397c5727611147503e36355a4f683737'
  .scan(/[0-7]\h/)
  .map { |x| x.prepend('0x').oct.chr }
  .join
```

I've opened a [bug](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11648) report at ruby-lang if anybody is interested...